# Actual Python 3.10 async implementation of serial port/uart communication?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, serial-port, uart

folks.
I'm writing some sort of scheduler that will send commands and receive responses to a hardware controller that is connected to the Linux-based system via a serial (UART) port. Currently it is FT232RL USB <-> UART bridge.

The scheduler itself is asynchronous and written using asyncio "in-code" Python module. There is no code that may block main loop. But here I'm facing the need of actually sending data to the controller via UART and receiving data from it. The "controller" will actually execute commands and perform actions with physical devices. The problem is that there is no "in core" standard Python module to communicate with external devices using serial ports. Especially the way asyncio does.

Is there is any actual maintained one that is supported by Python 3.10 that will allow me to make use of asyncio and make non-blocking data transmission via UART?

The pyserial-asyncio seems to be a good candidate. Any other modules to take a look at?